# How to integrate to find the view factor of two parallel disks of different radii?

Tags: thermodynamics, radiation, thermal-radiation, integration

You have two parallel coaxial disks of different radii. I have tables that give me the value as

$$F_{ij} = \tfrac{1}{2} [S - \sqrt{S^2 - 4(r_j/r_i)^2}]$$

where

$$S = 1 + \frac{1 + R_j^2}{R_i^2}$$

and:

$$R_i = \frac{r_i}{L}, R_j = \frac{r_j}{L}$$

$L$ being the distance between the two disks and $r_i$ , $r_j$ being the radius.

I am unable to write a suitable solvable integral for this. Is it all labor or can we use symmetry properties ?

Comment: Integral of what?

Comment: The view factor : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_factor#View_factors_of_differential_areas